# Domain Driven Desing applying in .Net with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, orm, domain-driven-design

I am learning the Domain Driven Design and I saw some concepts the following Aggregate, UnitOfWork,... I am reading the books that including java based applications. But Entity Framework is growing up in .Net framework. Entity Framework is including `DbContext`, `IDbSet`,...

Is there a nice sample that applied domain driven design in .Net

Matching the concepts

Comment: To be honest, I don't think you should use EF entities for your domain model. EF entities should be hidden behind your repositories and should be an implementation detail of your data access layer.

Comment: @Steven I agree 100%...unless EF code first approach is used. In such case a clean domain is perfectly achievable. You keep your entities as POCOs and move the mappings into separate classes inside infrastructure code together with the DbContext and other framework-related stuff. In short you don't have such thing as EF entities, you have your domain classes that the infrastructure code knows how to persist.

Comment: @dmusial but even with code first it is really hard to get a true domain model since aggregates hide much of their internals. Ifposdible, you'll have a pretty complex mapping.

Comment: "To be honest, I don't think you should use EF entities for your domain model" Steven if I create a Model Library that included model entities. Can I use it in Entity Framework? But Database is exist.

Comment: Well i Think you can get all the way with EF and code first. To write your own db Connection that map To your entities is a big effort... So be pragmatic and adapt To your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I personally think that Microsoft Spain has done a great job in providing a learning example. It's not for the "faint-hearted", and it's not the "only way to do it", but you may find it interesting. Have a look at https://microsoftnlayerapp.codeplex.com/ ?

Comment: I do not know have you ever read "Professional ASP.Net Design Patterns" book wrote by Scott Millett. There is a real application in this book named Agath's Storefront. THis application uses NHibernate and Domain Driven Desing. A Model library is created In this application, and models are mapped in Nhibernade DLL via XML files. But not used Entity Framework.